# How to check if a file with a certain string in its filename exists in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to print out an error message if a file with a "RDR_Config_Summary" in its filename does not exist in the directory. Some example filenames could be `er2_FCLS_RDR_Config_Summary.txt` or `er1_CDMA_RDR_Config_Summary.txt`. I am getting a syntax error for the following code:

```
cd $inputDir/$reviewDir
[[ ! grep "RDR_Config_Summary" ]] && echo -e "\nError: RDR Config Summary file was not found\n" && exit 1
```

Comment: I don't see a syntax error here. Are you sure you are using `bash`?

Comment: @chepner running op's code I get `-bash: conditional binary operator expected -bash: syntax error near \`"RDR_Config_Summary"'`

Comment: Oh, right; syntax error in the expression mini-language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd $inputDir/$reviewDir
ls | grep "RDR_Config_Summary" > /dev/null 2>&1
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo -e "\nError: RDR Config Summary file was not found\n" && exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`[[` is a command itself; you don't need it to run `grep`. However, you have nothing *to* run `grep` on. Use pathname expansion instead.

```
cd "$inputDir/$reviewDir"
shopt -s failglob
if ! { : *RDR_ConfigSummary*; } 2> /dev/null; then
  echo -e "\nError: RDR Config Summary file was not found\n";
  exit 1
fi
shopt -u failglob
```